# How does the scope work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't understand what's going on here and in what order. Could anybody give me a bit of clarification on how things work in this scope?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  scope :by_category, -> (slug) { joins(:category).where('categories.slug = ?', slug) if slug }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code:

```
scope :by_category, -> (slug) { joins(:category).where('categories.slug = ?', slug) if slug }
```

can be written like this:

```
scope :by_category, lambda do |slug|
  if slug
    joins(:category).where('categories.slug = ?', slug)
  end
end
```

A scope can be called on ActiveRecord::Relation objects or on a model itself (ActiveRecord::Base object).

Example:

```
# in model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :admin, lambda { where(is_admin: true) }

# in controller
@admins = User.admin # returns a list of User record where `is_admin` is true
```

---

Now, your scope is doing `joins(:category).where('categories.slug = ?', slug)`, what is going on here?

The relation `category` defined on your model (most likely a `belongs_to :category`) will be preloaded in a SQL query, and then try to find the categories having the attribute `slug` equal to the slug you gave to the scope. If any category is found then all Article records having this category will be "caught" (returned) by your scope.

Example:

```
Article.by_category('rails')
# => returns all articles which belongs to a category called 'rails'
# if no category with a slug equal to 'rails' exists in your DB,
# no article will be returned
```